# Is there "listener" mode in daily.co in react native?

Tags: react-native, dailyco

Is there a way to have "listener" mode in Daily.co where the user is not using the mic and is only subscribed listening to the other user?

I tried `Daily.join` but it automatically joins the room

```
const callObject = await Daily.createCallObject({
      url: dailyRoomUrl,
    });

    await callObject.join({
      userName: username,
      startVideoOff: true,
      startAudioOff: true,
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to have a "listener" mode in Daily.co where the user is only subscribed and can listen to the other user without using the microphone. To achieve this, you can set the `startAudioOff` option to `true` when joining the call, which will turn off the user's microphone upon joining.

In your code snippet, you have already set `startAudioOff: true`, which is the correct approach. However, you mentioned that the user is automatically joining the room. If you want to prevent automatic joining and instead have the user join as a "listener" after the initial join, you can modify your code as follows:

```js
const callObject = await Daily.createCallObject({
  url: dailyRoomUrl,
  userName: username,
  startVideoOff: true,
  startAudioOff: true,
});

// This will create the call object without joining the room

// Later, when you want to join the room as a listener:
await callObject.join();
```

By separating the call object creation and joining, you have more control over when the user actually joins the call. This way, you can create the call object with the desired settings (such as audio off), and then join the call later when you're ready for the user to start listening.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).